# Grafana Elastic Histogram

Tags: elasticsearch, graph, grafana, grafana-templating

I am making a graph in Grafana using Elasticsearch as datasource. I am using `time series` graph.

Vertical Axis: count of documents

Horizontal Axis: Latency in milliseconds

Sample Graph: [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQSlk.png)

As visible in above image, the latency on horizontal varies from 100ms to 700000ms. The graph is empty from 50000ms to around 600000ms. This is taking unnecessary space causing mess with entire graph.

Is there any way to show x-axis numbers in logarithmic mode? It can be done for y-axis, but don't see such option for x-axis.